# Vuetify Datepicker that opens a Modal / Dialog

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Forgive me for asking this silly question as I am still a newbie in Vue, Vuetify & Javascript.

I have the Vuetify Datepicker - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#usage displayed
on the home page and want to know if its possible to open a Modal / Dialog - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/ when the user click on a specific date.

I have created the Dialog component and have managed to open a Alert when clicking on a date.

Any help or point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to send your date picker click event to the dialog you want to open. You could use state management or send the event directly to the dialog.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#date-buttons
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

In date-picker: emit date-picker-click -> In v-dialog: on "date-picker-click" -> this.dialog = true